# Google Oauth2 in App Engine: Skip Account Selection

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I am working on a Google App Engine web app which exploits the Api Client Library (Python) to access drive and calendars.

When the user enters the app it is asked to log in with a Google Account. After that a second form is shown in which the Application is said to be not affiliated to Google and the user shall authorize it to access his data. In this second form the user can change the account (if it is logged with several). 
This sometimes lead to inconsistencies in the app as the users.get_current_user() returns the former Account while the services accessed through the library refer to the second account.

I have been strugling on this for a long time [Managing users authentication in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656280/managing-users-authentication-in-google-app-engine)

A solution would be to avoid the second account selection and forcing the user to authorize the application against the account which is currently logged.

Is there any way of doing so? 
I am using the Python decorator oauth_required() and oauth_aware()